# GADT record function fails where deconstruction succeeds

Tags: haskell, type-constraints, gadt

I'm trying to wrap my head around GADTs, and I suspect some magic is going on I don't understand.

Consider the following:

```
class C t

data T a where
  T :: (C a) => { getT :: a } -> T a

f :: C a => a -> ()
f = undefined

class D t where
  g :: t a -> ()

instance D T where
  g (T x) = f x
```

This is all good and compiles successfully.

Now consider a slightly different instance definition for T:

```
instance D T where
  g x = f (getT x)
```

This looks exactly the same as above, but there's a compile error. What's happening here? The data type `T` has no existential variables, it does have a simple constraint for it's only constructor but that's it.

Comment: “The key point about GADTs is that pattern matching causes type refinement.” — [GHC Users Guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1-rc2/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#generalised-algebraic-data-types-gadts). When you use pattern matching with an equation or `case`, the typechecker has an obvious scope in which to locally refine the type and add constraints to the context. The record accessor doesn’t “leak” the constraints to the surrounding context.

Answer (score 7):

What happens here is that the pattern match

```
g (T x) = f x
```

tells the typechecker that you have satisfied the constraint `C a` so you can use `f`. Without the pattern match you never introduce `C a` so it cannot satisfy the constraint.

It works such that a value `T something :: T a` also includes the dictionary for `C a` and makes it available when pattern matching on `T`. However, using `getT` does not give you any way to get at the dictionary for `C a` (as you can see from the type of `getT :: T a -> a`).

---

For posterity the error is

```
• No instance for (C a) arising from a use of ‘f’
  Possible fix:
    add (C a) to the context of
      the type signature for:
        g :: T a -> ()
• In the expression: f (getT x)
  In an equation for ‘g’: g x = f (getT x)
  In the instance declaration for ‘D T’
```

Comment: Indeed: pattern matching against `T` forces evaluation, so the typeclass dictionary can be extracted. Instead, application such as `f (getT y)` does not force the evaluation of `y`, since `f` might be lazy. So, in order to accept this, the compiler should either 1) evaluate the argument and break laziness (programmers will be astonished to discover this!) or 2) proceed with a "lazy dictionary", that would evaluate the argument as soon it is accessed (still somewhat astonishing). It's better to reject the code (or at least to introduce special types for this behavior).

Comment: @chi, I'm not so sure that this has to do with evaluation. More that the `T` constructor actually contains the dictionary for the `C a` while `getT` only extracts the `a`.

Comment: Well, you can't extract the dictionary until you reduce the expression to WHNF and expose the `T` constructor.